# How to change the format of how a DatePicker Dialog inputs it in EditText

Tags: java, android, date, android-studio, datepicker

I have an EditText and a button, when I click on the button it opens a DatePicker and it inputs the selected date into the EditBox. Its doing that in 24hr format, which is what I want... but it only shows to 1 digit if the part of the date is 1 digit. What I want to do is apply a format so that if it is 1 digit I want it to show 2 digits. Like so. 3/2/2017, I want it to be 03/02/2017.

It is doing the same thing with Time as well. I am not sure what part of the code too post, please let me know if you require code and of what and I will post it here.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

A couple options:

Use the **SimpleDateFormat** class.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
editBox.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
```

the format string MM/dd/yyyy will provide what you need.  You can also show time values if desired just by changing the format string (e.g. "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").  This assumes you're displaying a date stored in a **Date** object (called *date* in this example).

Or use **String.format**,

```
editBox.setText(String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d",month,day,year));
```

the %02 means use 2 positions with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
   int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
   int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();

    if(month < 10){

        month = "0" + month;
    }
    if(day < 10){

        day  = "0" + day ;
    }
    myText.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
```